# Cache tab content on Onsen ui

Tags: jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

So right i am working on mobile app project which was made from
**Onsen ui**, **Phonegap** and just **normal jquery**. I am using **ons-tabbar** as my main template.

My problem is When i tried to use **.append('some content')** to add new element to some tabs
it worked fine but when i changed that tab to the other tabs and go back to the same tab that 
already use append() function the last element that i add was gone.

So does someone know how to keep the element that was appended to that tab forever?

This is some of my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#test-headd').click(function() {
        /* Act on the event */
        $('#feeds-index-container').append('<h1 style="color: #fff;">testddd</h1>');
    });
});

<ons-tabbar class="tab-wrapper">
          <ons-tab page="recents-index.html" id="recents-button" no-reload>
            <img src="img/icon/recents_icon.png" class="icon-image" alt="">
            <span>Recents</span>
          </ons-tab>
          <ons-tab page="history-index.html" id="history-button" no-reload>
            <img src="img/icon/history_icon.png" class="icon-image" alt="">
            <span>History</span>
          </ons-tab>
          <ons-tab class="first-footer-button" id="feed-tab" page="feeds-index.html" no-reload active="true">
            <img src="img/icon/feed_box_icon.png" class="footer-image-bg" alt="">
            <img src="img/icon/feeds_icon_gold.png" class="icon-image" alt="">
            <span>Feeds</span>
          </ons-tab>
          <ons-tab page="profile-index.html" id="profile-button" no-reload >
            <img src="img/icon/profile_icon.png" class="icon-image" alt="">
            <span>Profile</span>
          </ons-tab>
          <ons-tab page="setting-index.html" id="setting-button" no-reload >
            <img src="img/icon/setting_icon.png" class="icon-image" alt="">
            <span>Setting</span>
          </ons-tab>
        </ons-tabbar>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The tabbar will reload the HTML when switching to another tab, so to get that behavior you will need to save the changes and then perform them again when the tab is opened again.

Since there's probably a lot of times when the developer wants the behavior you're describing it will be implemented in a later version.

Comment: How can i save the changes?